# Linux kernel crypto API from Solaris

Tags: c, linux, cryptography, kernel, solaris

I am porting some kernel sources from Solaris over to Linux, and I have 7 functions I need to make equivalent implementation. From Solaris, they are:

```
 int crypto_create_ctx_template(crypto_mechanism_t *mech,
           crypto_key_t *key, crypto_ctx_template_t *tmpl, int kmflag)
void crypto_destroy_ctx_template(crypto_ctx_template_t tmpl)
 int crypto_mac(crypto_mechanism_t *mech, crypto_data_t *data,
           crypto_key_t *key, crypto_ctx_template_t tmpl, crypto_data_t *mac,
           crypto_call_req_t *cr)
 int crypto_decrypt(crypto_mechanism_t *mech, crypto_data_t *ciphertext,
           crypto_key_t *key, crypto_ctx_template_t tmpl,
           crypto_data_t *plaintext, crypto_call_req_t *cr)
 int crypto_encrypt(crypto_mechanism_t *mech, crypto_data_t *plaintext,
           crypto_key_t *key, crypto_ctx_template_t tmpl, crypto_data_t *ciphertext,
           crypto_call_req_t *cr)
 crypto_mech_type_t crypto_mech2id(crypto_mech_name_t name)
```

My best guess is that the crypto API in Solaris lets me queue buffers to process, and a callback function for when the task has completed.

Under Linux, I suppose initially, my best options is to make _ctx_template do "little, do nothing", and implement encrypt and decrypt directly (blocking) and calling the CB itself. Eventually, use a kernel-thread that does the work concurrently.

Has anyone done any in-kernel crypto work before? The cryptodev appears to be for userland work?